# RowDataBound function of GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `DataTable` that contains 3 fields: `ACount`, `BCount` and `DCount`. If `ACount < 0` then I need to display 'S' in one of the columns of the `GridView`. If `ACount > 0` then I have to display 'D' in that column(in label). Same thing with `BCount` and `DCount`. How can I do this conditional check in the `RowDataBound` function?

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you using and what control are you trying to use, DataGridView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GridView [`OnRowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx) event is your friend:

```
<asp:gridview
  id="myGrid" 
  onrowdatabound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" 
  runat="server">

  <columns>
    <asp:boundfield headertext="ACount" datafield="ACount"  />
    <asp:boundfield headertext="BCount" datafield="BCount" />
    <asp:boundfield headertext="DCount" datafield="DCount" />
    <asp:templatefield headertext="Status">
      <itemtemplate>
        <asp:label id="aCount" runat="server" />
        <asp:label id="bCount" runat="server" />
        <asp:label id="dCount" runat="server" />
      </itemtemplate>
    </asp:templatefield>
  </columns>
</asp:gridview>

// Put this in your code behind or <script runat="server"> block
protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    return;
  }

  Label a = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("aCount");
  Label b = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("bCount");
  Label d = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("dCount");

  int ac = (int) ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["ACount"];
  int bc = (int) ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["BCount"];
  int dc = (int) ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["DCount"];

  a.Text = ac < 0 ? "S" : "D";
  b.Text = bc < 0 ? "S" : "D";
  d.Text = dc < 0 ? "S" : "D";
}
```

I'm not sure where you want the 'S' and 'D characters rendered, but you should be able to rejig to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me.... I must be misunderstanding something so I had to replace angled brackets with [ or ] for the ASP so just be aware of that.

```
 [asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Header"]
 [ItemTemplate]
 [asp:Label ID="theLabel" runat="server" Text='[%# Eval("DataSource").ToString() 
  %]'][/asp:Label]
 [/ItemTemplate]
 [/asp:TemplateField]


 protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label newLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("theLabel");

        if (newLabel.Text.Length > 20) //20 is cutoff length
        {
            newLabel.Text = lbl.Text.Substring(0, 20);

            newLabel.Text += "...";
        }
    }
}
```