# VB.Net Visual Studio - Static column with unique values for each row on GridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a created a databound gridview which will always remain the same size and what I would like to do is add a column onto the left of the gridview and assign static values to each row of the columnn:

```
       KS2             NoKS4     U     G     F
       No Prior        1         0     0     2
       1c              0         0     1     1
       1b              0         0     0     0
       1a              2         0     2     0
       2c              0         1     0     0
       2b              0         1     0     0
       2a              0         0     0     0
        ^              ^         ^     ^     ^
        |              |         |     |     |
(static column)        (From Stored Procedure)
```

So far I can generate the additional column full of static values using:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Text">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         KS2
                     </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

However, this generates a column with all values displaying as KS2 eg:

```
       KS2             NoKS4     U     G     F
       KS2             1         0     0     2
       KS2             0         0     1     1
       KS2             0         0     0     0
       KS2             2         0     2     0
       KS2             0         1     0     0
       KS2             0         1     0     0
       KS2             0         0     0     0
        ^              ^         ^     ^     ^
        |              |         |     |     |
(static column)        (From Stored Procedure)
```

Comment: Why not just have the SP return the column?

Comment: how do you determine what the static values will be?

Comment: @Ric they are just text that can be hardcoded

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I did think about that, but I would like to know if it's possible to do it the way I'm suggesting as well

Comment: you can add a label/literal control into the template and when databinding, access the control and set the .Text property there.

Comment: @Ric would I then be able to assign the different text for each row?

Comment: sure, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RowDataBound` event, link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).

Also, I have found an example (in C#, but it's very similar)
[rowdatabound-function-of-gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645415/rowdatabound-function-of-gridview).