# how to use table adapter to bind with asp gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tableadapter

i am trying to bind my grid to table adapter data, this is what i do :

```
DataSourceDepartement dpt = new DataSourceDepartement();

DataSourceDepartementTableAdapters.departementTableAdapter
         adapter = new DataSourceDepartementTableAdapters.departementTableAdapter();
gridDepartement.DataSource = adapter.GetDataDepartement();
gridDepartement.DataBind();
```

aspx file :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridDepartement" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
                    GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" AllowSorting="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox Id="cbSelect" runat="server"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>          
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="20px" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="20px" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Departement Code">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:label runat="server" ID="departementcode" ></asp:label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

but somehow, my gridview does not show its data, what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `RowDataBound` event, access the controls for the row in the `GridView` and then set the values:

[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645415/rowdatabound-function-of-gridview)

Also make sure no exceptions are being thrown!

Comment: hi ric, it is not working my OnRowDataBound event does not even triggered.

Comment: yes i did, by the way i've found the problem it was because i set my gridview AutoGenerateColumnSetting to false, but now the problem is if i turn it to true, my grid does not only generate data for bound column which i set in aspx file, but it also generate all column which returned from table adapter, so what should i do now?

Comment: In general, if you are binding to control within a gridview, then autogenerate columns should be set to false. then the rowdatabound event should be handled and at that point you can find the controls belonging to each row, and set the properties as you wish.